# Is it possible to get the process name of a Process object?

Tags: java

I have several process objects from which I'd like to get their names. Something like Thread-34 or Thread-74, etc.
I know I can build such with the pid, but is there something built in?

I know how to get their pid or info, but that doesn't help me to get their names.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
p = pb.start();

p.pid()
p.info()
```

Is it possible (Java 15)?

Comment: Have you looked at the Java API, and have you checked the results of the various properties of `Process` and `ProcessHandle.Info` (e.g. `ProcessHandle.Info#command()` seems to be a candidate for this)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I just did.  Don't see anything there that looks like a name.

Comment: Why would you not know, since it would be you who defined `command`?

Comment: @g00se _"Returns the executable pathname of the process."_ If that isn't what the OP is looking for, then I guess it is not available in Java.

Comment: @g00se: Presumably the code example is merely illustrative.

Comment: Where are these names “Thread-34” or “Thread-74” coming from? Why do you assume that this process has such a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `p.info().command()`. It returns the executable pathname of the process ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html#command())). Note that it returns an Optional object: you need to check if it has a value before getting the pathname string out of it:

```java
var pathname = p.info().command();
if (pathname.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(pathname.get());
}
```

---

If you would like to refer to your processes by custom names (like "Process-1", "Process-2", ...) then you can use a HashMap:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create processes with names
        var processes = new HashMap<String, Process>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            var processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
            var process = processBuilder.start();
            var processName = "Process-" + (i + 1); // Name can be anything you want
            processes.put(processName, process);
        }

        // List process names
        for (var processName : processes.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(processName);
        }

        // Refer to a process by name
        System.out.println(processes.get("Process-3").pid());
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Process-1
Process-3
Process-2
Process-5
Process-4
12780
```

Comment: Thanks Kol. Maybe I was expecting something like "Thread-56" or similar. That gives me : Optional[C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe] which is not much helpful for me, because this is what it return for other threads as well...

Comment: I extended my answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: So we must explicitly set the process name. Ok, thanks